# Extract MySQL fields of row into PHP variables and array

Tags: php, mysql, automation

I have a table with a whole bunch of fields and records in it (40+fields).

I use my MySQL result like so:

```
<?php
 $field1 = $row['field1'];
 $field2 = $row['field2'];
 $field3 = $row['field3']; 
?>
```

As you see, the variable name is the same as the field name.

How can I do this for all fields, without having to type em all out? Would be really awesome for when I add more fields!

I know about the `eval` function, however I am not sure of how to use it in this case.

Also, how can I generate an array with the results? Like so:

```
<?php
  $arr = array(
           'field1'=>$row['field1']
               );
?>
```

Comment: If you do such thing, make sure you __never__ use a column name as a variable when it does not represent the column. Since this will be really hard to do, I really advise you against it, because that means you might override other variables (which can go from breaking your script to exploiting your website)

Comment: are you sure you need all 40?

Comment: well, it means there is something wrong in your architecture

Comment: @Col - Not really - the fields are holding a value used to generate a design :)

Comment: Edited title so I am able to ask another question with same title, with the intention of making it fair to the person who answers it, in case it is not the already accepted answer that gets edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [extract()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php):

```
extract($row);
```

**However**, take great care you don't pollute your namespace with this function. Say you already have a variable named `$car`, and you have a field in your database called `car`. You could be unwittingly overwriting your existing variables!

It may be safer, then, to use:

```
extract($row, EXTR_SKIP); // don't extract variables that already exist in the namespace
```

**EDIT:** In regards to your edit, you don't need to create an array for the results... your $row array **is** the result. If you construct the array as in your edit, `$arr['field1'] = $row['field1']`, so why not bypass the construction of this array altogether and just use the original `$row`?

Comment: You can use the prefix settings of that function to help avoid that as well http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: - I actually have something to add to the question - should I ask another question, or just add it to this one?

Comment: @Jeff If it's a clarification for this question, you can ask in a comment or edit the question. If it's mostly a new question, create a new one.

Comment: @Christopher - I edited it, do tell if you think I should ask another one though!

Comment: Didn't know that - pretty new to PHP :)

Comment: You guys just transformed my huge ammount of code into like nothing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

The [`extract()`](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function does exactly this:

```
extract($row);
```

By default it will override any existing variable (e.g. if you already have a `field1` variable, it will override it). You can disable this by passing EXTR_SKIP as second parameter:

```
extract($row, EXTR_SKIP);
```

Or you can prefix all variables:

```
extract($riw, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'row');
```

Comment: So the 'row' will make the var be $rowfield1 ?

Comment: @Jeff Yep. In that example, it will prefix **all** the variables with 'row'.

Comment: Awesome - I edited my question though, if that could be solved too, it would be swell!

Answer (score 2):

> Also, how can I generate an array with the results?

```
$arr = $row;
```

Comment: Wow.. Is it really that simple? :)

Comment: According to your extremely short and vague question - yes.

Comment: @Jeff I see no use for separate variables then

Comment: @Jeff `$arr = $row` is somewhat a joke. Of course you can use $row variable which is all you need.

Comment: Yeah, true! :) I have one last thing to add though, but I feel I have to create another question for it, even though its pretty much the same exact topic.