# Automating output of MySQL rows in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, automation

Continuing from my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7295226/extract-mysql-fields-of-row-into-php-variables-and-array), I now know how to extract the fieldnames into variables with the result stored in them.

However, lets say I wish to output like this:

```
<?php
  echo "Here is field1: ".$row['field1'];
  echo "Here is field2: ".$row['field2'];
  echo "Here is field3: ".$row['field3']; 
?>
```

And I have over 40 fields in my table, so to avoid having to type them all out like the above, how can I automate it?

Comment: Don't forget to html-escape the filed contents. unless you know it contains HTML...

Comment: @bart - It was a foo-example - I am already escaping it. Was just making it easier for you guys to read, thats all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo "Here is '" . $key . "': " . $value . "<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    for($i = 1; $i < 40; $i++) {
        echo "Here is field" . $i . ": ".$row['field' . $i]; 
    }
?>
```

But I wonder, why do you have 40 columns in your table? Seems like you should redesign it.

Comment: The "field" prefix was a foo :)

Comment: I just realized that and I feel quite stupid ... Took the example a bit too literally. I should just down vote myself ;)

Comment: you took his question too literally. I doubt he has these silly numbers in real

Comment: And it would be `<=`, not `<`.

Comment: @Andreas - Don't worry, all good :) I did do that back when I started in VB though - "Button1, Button2..." :P

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
    echo "Here is ".$key.": ".$value;
}
```

Or I don't get it:)